# Simple software to track software/hardware maintenance warranty

Tags: windows, information-management

Something simple that you could possibly attach a document and it would alert when maintenance is about to fall off.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [ManageEngine ServiceDesk Plus](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/). It's simple and easy to use. You can manage complete asset inventory - hardware, software, software licenses, warranty, asset depreciation and so on. You can add attachments too. On license expiry, you will receive notifications through email as well as SMS.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a warranty tracking software “[SPICEWORKS](http://www.spiceworks.com/free-warranty-review-tracking-software/)” that automatically manage computer warranties and gives you an alert to remember your warranty expiration.

Hope this might be helpful to you.